# Multi Host : Docker Networking

Tags: docker

Say we have two hosts, how docker containers can connect to each other in this Docker cluster if both interfaces:

- docker0
- docker_gwbridge

have the same IP address in each host ?

Comment: Multi-host networking is a feature that is part of the new docker swarm mode

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/   Have you looked into this?

Comment: Overlay networks also existed before the new swarm mode and could be implemented with k/v stores like consul or etcd. This can still be done today if you do not enable the new swarm mode.

Comment: Yes I tested Swarm but I wanted to test OpenvSwitch for example, and I had this question in mind !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those networks are bridge networks that only exist on a single docker host. Containers assigned to only these networks will not be able to talk to containers on other hosts.

Multi-host networking is done with an "overlay" network and will show up with that driver instead of "bridge". The overlay driver relies on a global key/value store, such as consul, etcd, and it's now built into swarm with the raft backend. Assigning IP's is done by referencing this global key/value store so they should always be unique.

For more details, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/